# Wir sind (uns) uneinig

Tags: word-usage, reflexive, typo

> Trumps demokratischer Herausforderer bei der Präsidentschaftswahl am 3. November, Joe Biden, erklärte, wenn die Anschuldigungen in dem "Atlantic"-Artikel wahr seien, seien sie ein "weiteres Zeichen dafür, wie uneinig Präsident Trump und ich **uns** über die Rolle des Präsidenten der Vereinigten Staaten sind". Sollte er die Präsidentschaftswahl gewinnen, werde er "sicherstellen, dass unsere amerikanischen Helden wissen, dass ich hinter ihnen stehe und ihre Aufopferung ehren werde - immer", fügte Biden hinzu.

Is the uns I've emphasized necessary, or did the author of the article do a typo?

https://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/usa-donald-trump-soll-sich-veraechtlich-ueber-getoetete-soldaten-geaeussert-haben-a-b4026378-16d8-4641-b78b-a0bce3a2370a

Answer (score 1):

To have it shorter. You are asking, which of these sentences is correct:

> 1. Wir sind uneinig.
> 2. Wir sind uns uneinig.

Without changing the meaning you can replace *uneinig* by *nicht einig*:

> 3. Wir sind nicht einig.
> 4. Wir sind uns nicht einig.

The answer is: 2 and 4 are correct.

In German the phase *sich einig sein* (engl: *to agree*) always needs a reflexive pronoun.

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/einig#gb-1) lists some example sentences to show the usage of *einig sein:*

> - Schnell seien sie **sich einig geworden,** das Unternehmen gemeinsam zu gründen.
> - Sie **waren sich** schnell **einig,** daß es nun darum gehen mußte, das Gutachten Professor Mauls selbst zu erschüttern.
> - Sie **waren sich einig** in einem gutwilligen gleich wieder verleugneten Lächeln.
> - Ohne ausführliche Diskussion **waren** wir **uns einig,** uns »nicht antiautoritär« zu verhalten.
> - Die Minister **sind sich** über den Ernst der Lage **einig.**

---

In German there are some verbs and verb-like phrases that need a reflexive pronoun in dative case:

> - Ich gebe **mir** Mühe. = I do my best.
> - Ich mache **mir** Sorgen. I am worried.
> - Ich kann **mir** das nicht merken. = I can't remember that.
> - Er denkt **sich** nichts wenn er das macht. = He thinks nothing when he does that.

And *sich einig sein* also belongs to that list:

> - Wir sind **uns** einig. = We agree.

Comment: Similar constructions are: _sich sicher sein_, _sich bewusst sein_, _sich im Klaren sein_. Although they don't semantically "distribute" like _sich einig sein_.